# Odd behavior with SAS numeric comparison; precision issue?

Tags: sas, precision

I'm running a simple inequality filter in SAS as follows:

```
data my_data;
    set my_data;
    my_var = sum(parent_var1, -parent_var2)
run;

proc sql;
    select my_var format=32.32
    from my_data
    where my_var < 0.02;
quit;
```

I get the following result:

```
my_var
.0200000000000000000000000000000
.0200000000000000000000000000000
.0200000000000000000000000000000
(etc...)
```

The problem, in case it's not obvious, is that I want numbers *below* .02, but it looks very much like my number *is* .02.

According to the properties listed when I view my dataset, the length of `my_var` is set to 8. `parent_var1` and `parent_var2` are both decimal numbers, length 8 and format 8.5.

Can someone explain what might be going on here? Is there some hidden precision somewhere that I'm not able to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS only has floating point binary data type for numbers. There is no type that does decimal arithmetic instead.  So you might have a value that is slightly less than 0.02.

You might want to round your values to some fixed number of decimal places, say four or five.  Try this code on your data and check if you still see those 0.02 value.

```
data my_data;
   set my_data;
   my_var = round(sum(parent_var1, -parent_var2),0.00001) ;
   if my_var < 0.02 then put (my_var paren_var1 parent_var2) (= best32.8) ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to show the exact value, though?

Comment: To see exactly what is in the variable you can use HEX16. format to see the exact binary value that the floating point value has.  Compare it to what you get for the value 0.2 to see where any differences might be.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. It looks like the numbers are off by a single bit. (I tried the BINARY64. format as well, which makes it nice and explicit.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [FUZZ function](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p18pa7u3zufu9nn1ivv67uknw3i7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) which returns the nearest integer if the argument is *close enough*. However, you would need to multiply both sides of the where expression by 100 to make it work properly.

```
proc sql;
    select my_var format=32.32
    from my_data
    where fuzz(my_var * 100) < 2;
quit;
```

More information on why this happens with float point types you could find in the following papers/presentations:

- [DH08: Do Not Trust Your Own Computer generated Numbers - PHUSE EU Connect 2019 - Matthias Lehrkamp](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2019/dh/DH08.pdf), also [slides](https://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2019/dh/DH08_ppt.pdf)
- https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think simple rounding is a bit better in my case but the FUZZ function might come in handy in the future.